# Thrift php lib performance issue

Tags: php, rpc, thrift

I recently use php thrift client to call some service implemented by java thrift server.

But I found that when I transfer a large amount of complex data, php spent a lot of time serialize and deserialize data because of tens of thousands of `TBinaryProtocol::readXXX()` or `TBinaryProtocol::writeXXX()`
 calls.

Any good idea to optimize this?

Comment: I'd suggest to discuss this [on the mailng lists](https://thrift.apache.org/mailing) if you suspect a bug or problem within Thrift.

Answer (score 1):

The `TBufferedTransport` or `TFramedTransport` may help. The former only has a buffer in between to reduce I/O calls, while the latter also changes the transport stack by modifying the wire data (i.e. an Int32 holding the total length of the data block is inserted at the beginning).

Hence, `TBufferedTransport` is a purely local thing, in contrast `TFramedTransport` must be used on both client and server. Aside from that, both are working very similar.

Furthermore, some of the server types available require `TFramedTransport`, so for any new API it may be a good choice to add `TFramedTransport` from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you. I found that using TBinaryProtocolAccelerated with php extention thrift_protocol  is the best way.